# Working with Multiple Windows; Keeping one static

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a workbook and I created a "Menu" sheet that I want to serve as a thin navigation bar to launch all of the various macros/userforms that run in the workbook.

My plan is to have one window always set to the "Menu" sheet and just be a thin bar on the left side of the work area. The other window would take up the rest of the workarea and display all of the other various sheets.

How do I get the first window to always display the menu sheet and execute the macros launched from that window in the other window? Also, let me know if you have any better ideas to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why not put your macro buttons in the **QAT** ??

Comment: The ultimate plan is to send this sheet out for multiple people to use. If I create a custom tool bar, will it show up on other machines that open the workbook?

Comment: You may want to consider going  to a full custom ribbon addition with the **Custom UI Editor Tool**. See [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I found a relatively simple solution that seems to give me the result I want. At the start of each macro I added the following code:
`Windows("<window name here>").Activate` Once the target window is activated the menu window stays static. I also removed the tabs, scrollbar, and heading from my menu window to make it so users can't get off the menu page manually. Lastly, I added a line of code at the bottom of my macros to reselect the menu sheet in the menu window just to make sure it remains visible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing something similar. I took a different approach that you could adopt.

So I have a workbook with many sheets, and a main 'Control Panel' worksheet where the user inputs their data and run macro buttons to do lots of magical things(!)

I just placed all my macro buttons in Row 1 of the sheet and then used the "Freeze" Panes tool to freeze the top row. That way, if the user is on the Control Panel Sheet, the macro tools are always available regardless of where they are on the sheet.

I have set up the same buttons (which are contextually appropriate) on the other worksheets. So essentially the user can operate them from anywhere.

Just some food for thought :)

Comment: In theory you could keep a set of buttons on each worksheet, frozen in the same manner.

Comment: Yes, that is my intention! As not all the macros are applicable to all worksheets:- using the freezepanes method means I can present only the macro buttons that are of use for each sheet. :)